# Submitting additional documents UK Spouse Visa

Tags: united-kingdom, uk-visa

Due to time constraints, my wife and I have submitted everything for her UK Spouse visa using the priority service.

In our documentation, we provided copies of my mothers accommodation evidence as she will be housing us for the first few weeks whilst I locate a property for us.

Because I (preferably we) need to be back in the UK by the 5th of January, I asked my mum to send the originals in the post, and I submitted the documents as copies whilst waiting for the originals.

We have now received the originals. Is there anyway I can submit these originals to the ECO/Application center? I know they like to have the originals (although not mandatory for everything).

Edit: This is a Japan based application. The hub is in Manila.